# django if value of choice return value of other choice

Tags: django, comparison

I got 3 fields in my model category, primary and secundary.
and 2 choices   ATTRIBUTES and CATEGORIES. now i want the primary be added automatic depending on the value of the CATEGORIES choice.
My model choices and fields

```
class Skill(models.Model):
    ATTRIBUTES = (
        ('STR', 'Strength'),
        ('DEX', 'Dexterity'),
        ('CON', 'Constitution'),
    )
    CATEGORIES = (            #Primary attribute =
        ('ARCH', 'Archery'),  # Dexterity
        ('ARMO', 'Armor'),    # Constitution
        ('CRAF', 'Crafting'), # Strenght
        ('ELIX', 'Elixers'),  # Constitution
    )
    primary = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=ATTRIBUTES)    #added automatic
    secundary = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=ATTRIBUTES)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=CATEGORIES)
```

And then the method that gets a Skill object.category

```
def get_primary(category):
    if category == 'Archery':
        return ATTRIBUTES[1]
```

Problem is im not sure how i can play with the data i get form choices, and how to send back a choice to be saved in the object.
Can someone please help me out here?
Greets
Hans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make mapping dict with association of categories and attributes (if i understand you right):

```
attr_map = {
    'ARCH': 'DEX' # Archery -> Dextrerity
}
```

and use it in function:

```
def get_primary():
    #if category == 'Archery':
    #    return ATTRIBUTES[1]
    return attr_map[self.category]

    # or choice tuple if you need it
    return (attr_map[self.category],
            dict(self.ATTRIBUTES).get(attr_map[self.category]))
```

Comment: goign to try this, feels with the amount of skill categories i have, the use of a dictionary should be better.

Answer (score 1):

Enumeration lists like your `ATTRIBUTES`, `CATEGORIES` are lists of `('value', 'verbose_name')` tuples. The `value` gets written to the DB, and `verbose_name` get shown to the user. So, to check which category is assigned to the instance, you have to use `'value'`, e.g. `category == 'ARCH'`.

You can refer to enumeration list by using class, e.g. `Skill.ATTRIBUTES`. If you want to assign a choice, you have to use `'value'`. You can simply set it by assigning a string, like this `self.secondary = 'ELIX'` or by getting the string from the enumeration, like this `self.secondary = Skill.ATTRIBUTES[-1][0]`.

The best way is to define constants and use them everywhere, like this:

```
ARCHERY = 'ARCH'
ARMOR = 'ARMO'

DEX = 'DEX'

class Skill(models.Model):
    CATEGORIES = (
        (ARCHERY, 'Archery'),
        (ARMOR, 'Armor'),
        ...
    )
    ...

def get_primary(self):
    if category == ARCHERY:
        return DEX
```

Comment: okay im going to try this out, i guess for the return, i need to return the value as well?

Comment: I guess this could also work, i work with django and cant store 3 values in my choices. the dictionary is more elegant in my opinion.  thanks for the help tho

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of categories or may add categories later on, using a proper `Category` model would be a possibly better solution. It would also let you map categories to primary skill more easily:

```
ATTRIBUTES = (
    ('STR', 'Strength'),
    ('DEX', 'Dexterity'),
    ('CON', 'Constitution'),
)

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("name", max_length=32)
    primary = models.CharField("primary", max_length=3, choices=ATTRIBUTES)

class Skill(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categorie)
    @property
    def primary(self):
        return self.category.primary
    secundary = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=ATTRIBUTES)
```

Comment: Wont get mroe categories then the ones i have, but still, i think i like this solution as well

Comment: Just be warned that it will be a bit more heavy on SQL queries than your current design... You'll probably want to use `select_related("category")` clauses on your querysets to avoid the N+1 queries problem.